# Open a file that is in use by other program

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to access, via a powershell code inserted in a bat file, to a log file created by another program but it gives me the following error (spanish environment):

> Excepci¢n al llamar a "OpenRead" con los argumentos "1": "El proceso
>   no puede obtener acceso al archivo
>   'C:\Users\g\Documents\BAT\GrabI.log' porque est  siendo utilizado en
>   otro proceso.

In English:

> Exception calling "OpenRead" with "1" argument(s): "The process cannot
>   access the file 'C:\Users\g\Documents\BAT\GrabI.log' because it is
>   being used by another process."

The powershell code is:

```
@PowerShell  ^
    $N = 200; ^
    $fpath = 'Grab%1.log';  ^
    $fs = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($fpath);  ^
    $fs.Seek(-$N, 'End') ^| Out-Null;  ^
    $mystr = '';  ^
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $N; $i++)  ^
    {  ^
        $mystr = ($mystr) + ([char[]]($fs.ReadByte()));  ^
    }  ^
    Write-Host $mystr > logtmp%1.log
%End PowerShell%
```

Is there any way to do the Open that allow me to access the file in read mode even though it is in use?

Comment: Hi, maybe you can find a solution [here](http://community.idera.com/powershell/powershell_com_featured_blogs/b/tobias/posts/dealing-with-file-locks).

Comment: If the other program has the file opened as 'exclusive', then no.

Comment: Thanks, Bill_Stewart, I'm trying powershell to catch the 200 last characters from the log because when I tried it by means a "type Grab%1.log|find "writing"" in the bat file I only can read the 4096 first character from the log, but while the log doesn't reach them I have no problem. I think that if I can type the file it means that the other program hasn't opened the file as 'exclusive'. Am I wrong?

Comment: Thanks, sodawillow. I have read what is said in your link and I have tried some of the suggestions there but, for the moment I haven't resolved my problem.

Comment: the command `inuse`(resource pack) can help you. Note: it requires a restart.

Comment: Thanks SteveFest. Can you explain me anything about "resource pack"? What is that?

Comment: @GGG I didn't see the comment(due to no [at-sign]SteveFest was used). The resource pack is a pack, where updates are stored together, sometimes, these packs also contain extra commands.

Comment: @SteveFest. I apologize for my bad understanding of the ways to answer to the users. Thank you for trying to explain me what a resource pack is.

Comment: @GGG it's OK. One can't know a thing when one hasn't try.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution for my problem. Instead of opening the file I've used the Get-Content function. Something like this:

```
@PowerShell  ^
    $N = 200; ^
    $mystr = Get-Content 'Grab%1.log' ^| Select-Object -last 1;  ^
    Write-Host $mystr.substring($mystr.length-$N,$N) > logtmp%1.log
%End PowerShell%
```

Now I haven't any problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you have huge file it's better to use parameter **-tail 10**

```
Get-Content $fpath -tail $N
```